# Migrations failing on Heroku

Tags: django, python-3.x, heroku, django-cms, zinnia

I have a Django-CMS project running on a Cedar stack using Django 1.7.1 and Python 3 at Heroku.

I can create a migration just fine using: `heroku run python manage.py makemigrations` which returns:

```
Migrations for 'zinnia':
    0002_entry_content_placeholder.py:
        - Add field content_placeholder to entry
```

However, running the migration via: `heroku run python manage.py migrate` returns:

```
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: mptt, tagging, djangocms_admin_style, localflavor, django_comments, robots, ckeditor, sekizai, compressor, cmsplugin_plaintext, storages
  Apply all migrations: admin, cms, zinnia, sessions, contenttypes, sites, auth, djangocms_link, djangocms_file, djangocms_picture, djangocms_text_ckeditor, menus
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
  Installing custom SQL...
  Installing indexes...
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
  Your models have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration,
      and so won't be applied.
  Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run
      'manage.py migrate' to apply them.
```

Re-running `makemigrations` and `migrate` simply returns the same error statement. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

im not so sure on that one, but after you ran the Migration, the file created:

**0002**_entry_content_placeholder.py

is as you notice, the second migration file.
If its an option for you, you could try to delete/rename the migration folder/files and run makemigrations again.
I got kinda the same error some time ago, and if i remember right, that did the trick.

Sorry for bad english